# How to access application preference files?

Tags: settings

A while ago I saw this video which explained how automating was better and faster than backing up your entire disk. It went into how one would, in the event of a major data loss, run a backup script which re-downloads all their applications and even resets the small things such as dock position, background image, etc. The script would even reset application level settings for example the theme & font size I chose for VS Code. Problem is, it never went into how to actually create such a script. So, I tried to make my own. It does mostly everything except for the last part. I have no idea how to set application level settings through the command line. Do Ubuntu applications have a common config file or something of that nature that I can modify?

Comment: VS Code theme and Font Setting?? Is it the Main Question??

Comment: Do you have a link to the video (in your browser history)? Seeing the video would help explain your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Linux application configuration files are stored in your `~/.config/` folder (which is `$HOME/.config/`).

As referenced here [VSCode: Docs - User and Workspace Settings](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getstarted/settings/), VS Code stores its settings in:

`$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Unfortunately there is no standard location where all applications store there settings but you should find that most will be in `$HOME/.config/` so backing up this folder would cover most.

Some may store configurations directly into your home folder so you will need to research the specific applications you need to backup.